# Javascript foreach calculation

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do some calculation for array of values but the system is calculation for the first row only.

```
<script>
  function calc() 
        {
    
        var eb_rate = document.getElementById('bm_eb_rate[]').value;
        var eb_cb = document.getElementById('bm_eb_cb[]').value;
        var eb_ob = document.getElementById('bm_eb_ob[]').value;

        var consumed = eb_cb - eb_ob;
        document.getElementById('ui_consumed[]').value = consumed;  

        var amount = consumed * eb_rate; 
        document.getElementById('ui_amount[]').value = amount.toFixed(3);  

        var vat = amount * .05;
        document.getElementById('ui_vat[]').value = vat.toFixed(3);  

        var netamount = amount + vat;
        document.getElementById('ui_netamount[]').value = netamount.toFixed(3);            
            
        }   
</script>
```

View

```
<td><input class="form-control" onkeyup="calc()" id="bm_eb_rate[]" type="text" name="ui_rate[]"
                  value="{{ $c->bm_eb_rate}}"></td>
              <td><input class="form-control" id="bm_eb_ob[]" type="text" name="ui_omr[]" value="{{ $c->bm_eb_ob}}">
              </td>
              <td><input class="form-control" onkeyup="calc()" id="bm_eb_cb[]" type="text" name="ui_cmr[]"
                  value="{{ $c->bm_eb_cb}}">
              </td>

              <td><input class="form-control text-right" type="text" name="ui_consumed[]" id="ui_consumed[]" readonly>
              </td>

              <td><input class="form-control text-right" type="text" name="ui_amount[]" id="ui_amount[]" readonly>
              </td>

              <td><input class="form-control text-right" type="text" name="ui_vat[]" id="ui_vat[]" readonly>
              </td>

              <td><input class="form-control text-right" type="text" name="ui_netamount[]" id="ui_netamount[]" readonly>
              </td>
```

Can any one please help me to resolve it.

Form design attached for better understanding https://ibb.co/zHkSNR4

Comment: `getElementById` selects a single element, by its ID. It assumes the ID is unique - which it should be. If you're creating multiple elements with the same ID (which it sounds like you might be), that's a design flaw. Broadly, what you need to do is adjust your calc function so it knows which row it's being applied to.

Comment: HTML IDs must be unique over the page. All of your rows use identical IDs for each of the inputs.

Comment: Is there any alternative method to achieve this easily?